# Stealing a "play at any time" item as a thief in Munchkin?

Tags: munchkin

A thief went to steal the Demonic Wishing Eye (Adventure Time Munchkins) by discarding a card and then declaring "I am going to steal the demonic wishing eye".

The Demonic Wishing Eye has the "PLAY AT ANY TIME" text on the top. The owner of the Demonic Wishing Eye therefore decided to play it straight away, before the thief had rolled the dice and hence completed the attempted steal.

The owner's justification was that it had the "play at any time" text. The thief did not think this was fair.

The group and owner of the game could see both sides to the argument as to why the thief would/should be able to steal it without the person playing it and vice versa. We were all wondering if there is an official rule for this interaction, the interaction being if the thief can steal the item before they can play it, or if they can play it before the thief can steal it after the thief declares they are going to and discards a card.

Answer (score 9):

You say the thief went to steal the item, but here's no such game mechanic. Either the thief has stolen the item, or they haven't. Stealing is not something that has a duration, so you can't "interrupt" it. There's no mechanism for time travel or precognisence in Munchkin, so an action (e.g. stealing) must be completed before another one can be started.

If the thief hasn't stolen the item, the owner original (and current) owner can play it.

If the thief has stolen the item, the owner original owner can't play it since they no longer own it.

Comment: The thief said "I am going to steal the demonic wishing eye" after discarding a card but before they rolled the owner of the demonic wishing eye played it since it has the play at any time text.

Comment: That's all one game action.

Comment: So the playing of the demonic wishing eye was not allowed?

Comment: Correct. Reversing time is not natural. It's not something you can do without rules to support it. A stolen card can't be used.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up! Was mainly the "play at any time" ruling/text on the demonic wishing eye that made things go into a grey area, haha

Comment: The "play at any time" simply means you can play it on a turn other than your own. Unless the card specifically says it blocks, interrupts, or otherwise changes another action, it couldn't be played until after the initial action (the theft) is resolved.

Comment: Think of it this way: the original owner would have to know beforehand that the item is going to be stolen, so (s)he should have had a rule in place like "I'll use this item one second before it gets stolen." Obviously, this does not work, since the thief does not go to the would-be-victim to announce the theft, just attempts it and either succeeds or fails. The victim only learns of the outcome after it has been decided so can't act before.